# Auto run when an appointment is updated

Tags: vba, outlook

I would like to automatically run a macro when an appointment is updated.

For my test, I wish this macro displays the subject of the appointment.

Answer (score 1):

You want the ItemChange event http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865866%28v=office.14%29.aspx

```
Public WithEvents myOlItems As Outlook.Items 

Public Sub Application_Startup() 
  Set myOlItems = _
    Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar).Items 
End Sub 

Private Sub myOlItems_ItemChange(ByVal Item As Object) 
    debug.print item.subject
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by creating a rule in Outlook, and will start a macro.  If you have your macro working right, then you need only set the rule.  First:

```
Sub Sub_name(MyMail As MailItem)
'Working Code
End Sub
```

Then, set the condition to "which is a meeting invitation or update", actions are "run a script" Check on it, then click on the "script" link and select Sub_name.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it doesn't work. The rule works only with email. I would like autorun macro when any event in calendar is updated not only meeting.

Comment: Do you want it to run when you update an appointment or someone else does , which results in an email